# how to display custom taxonomy on an archive page?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

```
<?php get_header();?>
<?php
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$shahbaz = new WP_Query( 
    array(

        'order'         => 'ASC',
        'post_type'     => 'services',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => '9',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'basics',
                'field'    => 'taxonomy',
                'terms'    => 'taxonomy',
            ),
        ),



    ),
);
?>
<?php
$categories = get_the_terms( get_the_id(), $basics-slug );

if ( is_array( $categories ) ) {

    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> ';
    }

}
?>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: You can create custom taxonomy archive template. Please refer this **https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/**

Answer (score 0):

I'm only going to focus on the category listing you have in the code above and ignore the custom query since that's not what you're asking about.

```
<?php
// I assume the custom taxonomy slug is "basics"
$categories = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'basics' );

// get_the_terms returns false, a wp error, or an array of term objects.
if ( $categories && ! is_wp_error( $categories ) ) {

    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        // get_term_link requires taxonomy slug as the second parameter.
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $category->term_id, 'basics' ) ) . '" title="' . sprintf( esc_html__( 'View all posts in %s' ), esc_html( $category->name ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $category->name ) . '</a> ';
    }
}
?>
```

I adjusted a few details. Inline comments should provide some detail. I also added escaping to the output since this is a best-practice.